# Computation radius of convergence: $f(z)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} n\cdot (-1)^n 3^{n+1} z^{2n+1}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series

So, the title says everything what to do. I've want to compute the radius with the root test. First I simplify this a bit:

$$\begin{align*} f(z)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n\cdot n\cdot 3^{n+1} z^{2n+1}&= 3\cdot \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} (-3)^n\cdot n \cdot z^{2n+1}\\ 
\end{align*}$$

So I know this proposition:

> If $P(z)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} c_n(z-z_0)^n$ converges, thant $P'(z)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} n\cdot c_n(z-z_0)^{n-1}$ converges too.

Adapt on my series I want to compute the radius for this series:
$$F(z)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} (-3)^n z^{2(n+1)}$$

Unfortunately I do not know, how to handle with the exponent of $z$.

Is the idea correct? Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't need to rely on the highlighted theorem in the OP since $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{n}=1$.

Then, from the root test we have

$$\limsup_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}=\limsup_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{\left|(-1)^n\,n\,3^{n+1}\,z^{2n+1}\right|}=3|z|^2<1$$

whenever $|z|<1/\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible, to get this without the root test?

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  And the ratio test is equally effective here.  -Mark

Comment: Ah okay! But with this I get $\frac{1}{3z}$. How I has deal with the exponent of the $z$?

Comment: We let $a_n=(-1)^n\,n3^{n+1}z^{2n+1}$ and apply the root test as shown in the solution herein.

Answer (score 1):

The coefficients of this power series are 
$$ a_{2n+1} = (-1)^n \cdot n \cdot 3^{n+1}, \quad a_{2n} = 0. $$
There's a well-known [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Hadamard_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem) for calculating the radius of convergence $R$: 
\begin{align*}
\frac 1R 
& = \limsup_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{|a_n|} \\
& = \limsup_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[2n+1]{n \cdot 3^{n+1}} \\
& = \sqrt{3}. 
\end{align*}